# VLC Unmet Dependencies

Tags: linux, installation, vlc-media-player, apt-get, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Ubuntu such that it is split into 2 partitions (mounted as `/` and `/home`)

After running `sudo apt-get install vlc`, I get the following error on a **near fresh install** of **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS** (Xenial Xerus).

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

*What would be the easiest way of correcting the problem?*

I have tried `sudo apt-get clean`, `sudo apt-get update`, and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before running `sudo apt-get install vlc` again.

I have also tried to install `libgles1-mesa` with `sudo apt-get install libgles1-mesa` but returns with an error (see linked question)

I'm not sure if this is possible, but can I just reinstall the core Linux files to the `/` partition from the original installer (that I still have) and hope that `libgles1-mesa` appears?
(without losing any of my files or application settings)

Note: I appear to be having the same problem as the OP of https://askubuntu.com/q/889356/ but the Ubuntu versions differ.

Comment: *sudo apt-get -f install*?

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were 2 repositories in source lists containing vlc packages:

1. [Official vlc repo](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily) ppa:videolan/stable-daily;
2. [Ubuntu universe repo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

In first repo there were newer vlc packages, so `sudo apt-get install vlc` caused installation from first source.

The solution was to purge all packages from first source and remove this source list

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Next install vlc from Ubuntu Universe repo

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that you had problems with unmet dependencies like I did, there is solution to add PPA `ffmpeg-4` and then you will be able to install it properly:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/vlc-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Source: https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vlc-3